# How to insert existing table data in to another table in the database using option select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, simple-form-for

I am saving data in to my `fridges` table with all of its attributes like `Name`, `Image`, `Description`, etc.

But I want to save data in to another table name `ingredients` using option select in ruby on rails.

E.g. I want when I select option from the option select like 'Apple' then all the details about 'Apple' like apple image,description, amount will save in ingredients table and also show.

For this i am using the code for option select is

```
<%= f.collection_select(:Name, Fridge.where(user_id: '1'), :Name, :Name) %>
```

[image]

When data save it will display like this Apple image, amount, description etc that is already save in database.

[image]

Comment: May I know why you want to save the same data in both fridges and ingredients table. Can you explain the workflow so you will get a better solution.

Comment: Yes because i don't want people upload apple image and enter apple image description in their fridge.They only select apple using option select and then apple amount and image  save in data base with by default image.

Comment: For that you can give a relation between the two models. fridge model will have has_many :ingredients and ingredients model belongs_to :fridge. Add fridge_id in ingredients table. So calling fridge.ingredients will bring in all the ingredients present in the fridge. I hope that is the workflow you require. Have a read of this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I know the relations but  you don't understand what i want or i say.i mean i select apple and save it.it will save all of the data related to apple is in new table.